# Efficient way to build table within database or update it using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a headless application that does either of two things.

1. If table does not exist within database create it and copy all the data over

OR

2. If table exists update it

Now I usually use access layers but this application is a bit older so I can't. This is what I've written.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace FPS_ClientTable_Mirroring
{
    class DoWorkController
    {
        private ApplicationSettings applicationSettings;

        internal int Start(ApplicationSettings applicationSettings)
        {

            string sourceCS = applicationSettings.MSWConnectionString;
            string destinationCS = applicationSettings.ClientTableConnectionString;
            int doesDbExist = 0;


            try
            {
                this.applicationSettings = applicationSettings;
                DateTime yesterday = applicationSettings.ProcessingDate.AddDays(-1);

                applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Checking for EODTable within ClientTable");
                SqlConnection connectionClientTable = new SqlConnection(destinationCS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('dbo.EODTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", connectionClientTable);
                connectionClientTable.Open();
                doesDbExist = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                if (doesDbExist == 1)
                {
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Found EODTable within ClientTable");
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Updating EODTable within ClientTable");
                    connectionClientTable.Close();

                    using (SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand("Select * from EODTable where TxnDT = @yesterday", mswConnection);
                        cmdCopyData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yesterday", yesterday));
                        mswConnection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection ClientTableConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationCS))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ClientTableConnection))
                                {
                                    bc.DestinationTableName = "EODTable";
                                    ClientTableConnection.Open();
                                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);




                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Finished updating EODTable within ClientTable");
                }
                else
                {
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("EODTable was not found within ClientTable");
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Creating EODTable within ClientTable");



                    SqlCommand buildTableCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE EODTable(ID bigint, RecID char(64), rectype char(1), mercid varchar(15), termid char(8), edcbatch char(3), batchprdt char(8), batchsrc char(13)");
                    buildTableCommand.Connection = connectionClientTable;
                    buildTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connectionClientTable.Close();

                    using (SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand("Select * from EODTable", mswConnection);
                        mswConnection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection ClientTableConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationCS))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ClientTableConnection))
                                {
                                    bc.DestinationTableName = "EODTable";
                                    ClientTableConnection.Open();
                                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Finished creating EODTable within ClientTable");
                }


                applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Checking for EODPayments within ClientTable");

                SqlCommand cmdCheckMrPayment = new SqlCommand("SELECT CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('dbo.EODPayments', 'U') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", connectionClientTable);
                connectionClientTable.Open();
                doesDbExist = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCheckMrPayment.ExecuteScalar());

                if (doesDbExist == 1)
                {
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Found EODPayments within ClientTable");
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Updating EODPayments within ClientTable");
                    connectionClientTable.Close();

                    using (SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand("Select * from EODPayments where TransactionDate = @yesterday", mswConnection);
                        cmdCopyData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yesterday", yesterday));
                        mswConnection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection ClientTableConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationCS))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ClientTableConnection))
                                {
                                    bc.DestinationTableName = "EODPayments";
                                    ClientTableConnection.Open();
                                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);



                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Finished updating EODPayments within ClientTable");
                }
                else
                {
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("EODPayments was not found within ClientTable");
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Creating EODPayments within ClientTable");



                    SqlCommand buildTableCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE EODPayments(ID bigint, ProdID bigint, MercID nchar(15), Currency nchar(3), DbCr nchar(1), Amount float, " +
                        "Institution nchar(10), Transit nchar(10), AccountNumber nchar(16), EsiAppID nchar(10), TxnType int, ProdType nchar(1), TxnCode nchar(10), TxnDesc nchar(56), " +
                        "TransactionDate datetime, CoreBankingID bigint, Processed bit, ProcessedDate datetime, DataWarehouse bit, DataWarehouseDate datetime, GLInstitution nchar(10), " +
                        "GLTransit nchar(10), Converted bit, OriginalAmount float, OriginalCurrency nchar(3), Rate float, EntryID nvarchar(32), GLID nvarchar(32), NewCurrency char(3), SendRate bit) ");
                    buildTableCommand.Connection = connectionClientTable;
                    buildTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connectionClientTable.Close();

                    using (SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand("Select * from EODPayments", mswConnection);
                        mswConnection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection ClientTableConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationCS))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ClientTableConnection))
                                {
                                    bc.DestinationTableName = "EODPayments";
                                    ClientTableConnection.Open();
                                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Finished creating EODPayments within ClientTable");
                }

                applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Checking for EODRentals within ClientTable");

                SqlCommand cmdCheckRentalFees = new SqlCommand("SELECT CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('dbo.EODRentals', 'U') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END", connectionClientTable);
                connectionClientTable.Open();
                doesDbExist = Convert.ToInt32(cmdCheckRentalFees.ExecuteScalar());

                if (doesDbExist == 1)
                {
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Found EODRentals within ClientTable");
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Updating EODRentals within ClientTable");
                    connectionClientTable.Close();

                    using (SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand("Select * from EODRentals where DateProcessed = @yesterday", mswConnection);
                        cmdCopyData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yesterday", yesterday));
                        mswConnection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection ClientTableConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationCS))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ClientTableConnection))
                                {
                                    bc.DestinationTableName = "EODRentals";
                                    ClientTableConnection.Open();
                                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);



                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Finished updating EODRentals within ClientTable");
                }
                else
                {
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("EODRentals was not found within ClientTable");
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Creating EODRentals within ClientTable");



                    SqlCommand buildTableCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE EODRentals(ID bigint, Year nchar(4), Month nchar(12), DateProcessed datetime, CoreBankingID bigint, " +
                        "MerchantRecordID bigint, TerminalRecordID bigint, DeployedDate datetime, RecoveredDate datetime, MonthlyFee float, IsProRated bit, DaysActive int, TotalFee float, " +
                        "IsPinPad bit, Currency nchar(3)) ");
                    buildTableCommand.Connection = connectionClientTable;
                    buildTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connectionClientTable.Close();

                    using (SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand("Select * from EODRentals", mswConnection);
                        mswConnection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlConnection ClientTableConnection = new SqlConnection(destinationCS))
                            {
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ClientTableConnection))
                                {
                                    bc.DestinationTableName = "EODRentals";
                                    ClientTableConnection.Open();
                                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    applicationSettings.Logger.Info("Finished creating EODRentals within ClientTable");
                }

                return 0;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                applicationSettings.Logger.Fatal(ex.ToString());
                return applicationSettings.DefaultFailedExitCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping if I can get an idea of how to make this a bit more efficient in what it does. I also am not sure what is the best way to deal with error handling such as in between creating the table the connection is lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of redundant code. Also, the `Start` method is very long and difficult to read. Basically, it executes three times the same procedure applied to different tables. The idea is to create a parametrized method that can be called three times for the three tables. This increases the maintainability of the code. Its signature is

```cs
private int CreateOrUpdateTable(
    string tableName, string dateColumn, string createTableSql)
```

We can make the code more readable by creating some helper methods. The time to call methods (a few nanoseconds) is negligible compared to the time it takes to perform operations on the DB (milliseconds to seconds or even minutes). Even for milliseconds we have a factor of 1 million to the nanoseconds.

```cs
private void LogInfo(string message)
{
    applicationSettings.Logger.Info(message);
}

private static bool TableExists(SqlConnection connection, string tableName)
{
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand(
        $"SELECT CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('dbo.{tableName}', 'U') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END",
        connection);
    return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
}
```

Both cases (table exists or not) use the same code to execute a bulk copy. We extract it to a method as well:

```cs
private static void ExecuteBulkCopy(
    string tableName, SqlConnection connectionClientTable, SqlCommand cmdCopyData)
{
    using SqlDataReader rdr = cmdCopyData.ExecuteReader();
    using var bc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionClientTable);
    bc.DestinationTableName = tableName;
    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);
}
```

We can use the new handy using declarations (since C# 8.0 I think). They do not require nested code blocks as the using statements do.

You create, open, and close the same connections at different places. By creating and opening both connections before the if statement, we can simplify further. Also closing the connections explicitly is not necessary, as the using declarations (or statements) do it automatically.

We end up with this implementation:

```cs
private int CreateOrUpdateTable(string tableName, string dateColumn, string createTableSql)
{
    string sourceCS = applicationSettings.MSWConnectionString;
    string destinationCS = applicationSettings.ClientTableConnectionString;

    try {
        LogInfo($"Checking for {tableName} within ClientTable");

        using SqlConnection connectionClientTable = new SqlConnection(destinationCS);
        connectionClientTable.Open();

        using SqlConnection mswConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceCS);
        mswConnection.Open();

        if (TableExists(connectionClientTable, tableName)) {
            LogInfo($"Found {tableName} within ClientTable");
            LogInfo($"Updating {tableName} within ClientTable");

            using var cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand($"Select * from {tableName} where {dateColumn} = @yesterday", mswConnection);
            DateTime yesterday = applicationSettings.ProcessingDate.AddDays(-1);
            cmdCopyData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yesterday", yesterday));
            ExecuteBulkCopy(tableName, connectionClientTable, cmdCopyData);

            LogInfo($"Finished updating {tableName} within ClientTable");
        } else {
            LogInfo($"{tableName} was not found within ClientTable");
            LogInfo($"Creating {tableName} within ClientTable");

            var buildTableCommand = new SqlCommand(createTableSql, connectionClientTable);
            buildTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var cmdCopyData = new SqlCommand($"Select * from {tableName}", mswConnection);
            ExecuteBulkCopy(tableName, connectionClientTable, cmdCopyData);

            LogInfo($"Finished creating {tableName} within ClientTable");
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        applicationSettings.Logger.Fatal(ex.ToString());
        return applicationSettings.DefaultFailedExitCode;
    }
}
```

The `Start` method becomes

```cs
internal int Start(ApplicationSettings applicationSettings)
{
    this.applicationSettings = applicationSettings;

    int result = CreateOrUpdateTable("EODTable", "TxnDT", "CREATE TABLE EODTable ...");
    if (result != 0) return result;

    result = CreateOrUpdateTable("EODPayments", "TransactionDate", "CREATE TABLE EODPayments ...");
    if (result != 0) return result;

    return CreateOrUpdateTable("EODRentals", "DateProcessed", "CREATE TABLE EODRentals ...");
}
```

The lengthy create table statements could be created as string resources of the project. This allows you to write them with line breaks and indentations and does not clutter the C# code.

Comment: Loved this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an abstract class for constructing minimal `Sql` protected methods such as `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteScalar`, and `ExecuteReader` ..etc. these methods would be used in inherited classes (Repositories). So, each repository would work with only one table, which would give you a scoped work. This would give you more flexibility and maintainability to your project.

So, you can start with an abstract class :

```
public abstract class SqlRepoistoryBase
{
    private readonly string _connectionString; 
    
    protected SqlRepoistoryBase(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected void ExecuteCommand(string query)
    {   
        try
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
            }
            
            using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open(); 
                command.ExecuteCommand();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            applicationSettings.Logger.Fatal(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    
    protected object ExecuteScalar(string query)
    {   
        try
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
            }
            
            using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open(); 
                return command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            applicationSettings.Logger.Fatal(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    //...etc
}
```

then, you will do a class for `EODTable` only, which would contain its logic, something like :

```
public class SqlEoDRepoistory : SqlRepoistoryBase 
{
    public SqlEoDRepoistory(string connectionString) 
    : base(connectionString)    { }
    
    private bool IsTableExist()
    {
        const string query = $"SELECT CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('dbo.EODTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
        
        var queryResult = ExecuteScalar(query);
        
        return int.TryParse(queryResult?.ToString(), out int queryResultInt) && queryResultInt == 1;
    }
    
    private void CreateIfNotExists()
    {
        if(!IIsTableExist())
        {
            const string query = "CREATE TABLE EODTable(ID bigint, RecID char(64), rectype char(1), mercid varchar(15), termid char(8), edcbatch char(3), batchprdt char(8), batchsrc char(13)";
            ExecuteCommand(query);
        }
    }
    
    
    public void CopyData()
    {
        if(!IIsTableExist())
        {
            const string query = "CREATE TABLE EODTable(ID bigint, RecID char(64), rectype char(1), mercid varchar(15), termid char(8), edcbatch char(3), batchprdt char(8), batchsrc char(13)";
            ExecuteCommand(query);
        }
        
        const string query = "Select * from EODTable where TxnDT = @yesterday";
        
        var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("@yesterday", yesterday)
        };
        
        // implement CopyFrom in the base, and reuse it in this class
        CopyFrom(query, parameters, destinationTableName: "EODTable");
        
    }
    
    //.... etc 
}
```

now in the main class `DoWorkController` would reduce the code to something like :

```
public class DoWorkController 
{
  private ApplicationSettings applicationSettings;
  private readonly SqlEoDRepoistory _eodTableRepoistory;
  
  internal int Start(ApplicationSettings settings)
  {
      
      try
      {
        _eodTableRepoistory = new SqlEoDRepoistory(settings.MSWConnectionString);
        _eodTableRepoistory.CopyData();
        
        // you do the same for the EODPayments
        
        return 0;
      }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        applicationSettings.Logger.Fatal(ex.ToString());
        return applicationSettings.DefaultFailedExitCode;
    }
  }
    
}
```